# Custom designer for child FlowLayoutPanel in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, designer, flowlayoutpanel

I have created a `StackingControl`, which is basically a `UserControl` that contains a `FlowLayoutPanel` (and a panel as a footer). The purpose of this `StackingControl` is to hold a bunch of controls of the same type, derived from `BrickControl`.

My whole code looks like this:

```
    [Designer(typeof(StackingControlDesigner))]
    public partial class StackingControl : UserControl
    {
        public StackingControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(this.flowPanel, new DesignerAttribute(typeof(StackingControlContentDesigner)));
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public Panel ContentPanel
        {
            get { return flowPanel; }
        }

        public Type ContainedType
        {
            get
            {
                if (flowPanel.Controls.Count > 0)
                    return flowPanel.Controls[0].GetType();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }




    public class StackingControlContentDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
    {
        private StackingControl parent;

        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);
            // first parent is TableLayoutPanel; then StackingControl
            parent = (StackingControl)this.Control?.Parent?.Parent;
        }

        protected override void PostFilterAttributes(IDictionary attributes)
        {
            base.PostFilterAttributes(attributes);
            attributes[typeof(DockingAttribute)] = new DockingAttribute(DockingBehavior.Never);
        }

        protected override void PostFilterProperties(IDictionary properties)
        {
            base.PostFilterProperties(properties);
            var propertiesToRemove = new string[] { "Dock", "Anchor", "Size", "Location", "Width", "Height", 
                "MinimumSize", "MaximumSize", "AutoSize", "AutoSizeMode", "Visible", "Enabled" };
            foreach (var item in propertiesToRemove)
            {
                if (properties.Contains(item))
                    properties[item] = TypeDescriptor.CreateProperty(this.Component.GetType(),
                                       (PropertyDescriptor)properties[item], new BrowsableAttribute(false));
            }
        }

        public override bool CanParent(Control control)
        {
            if (!(control is BrickControl))
                return false;
            if (parent.ContainedType == null)
                return true;
            return parent.ContainedType.Equals(control.GetType());
        }

        public override bool ParticipatesWithSnapLines => false;
    }
    


    public class StackingControlDesigner : ParentControlDesigner
    {
        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);
            var contentPanel = ((StackingControl)this.Control).ContentPanel;
            EnableDesignMode(contentPanel, "ContentPanel");
        }

        public override bool CanParent(Control control) => false;
        protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs de) => de.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        protected override IComponent[] CreateToolCore(ToolboxItem tool, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool hasLocation, bool hasSize) => null;
    }
```

**Problem:** When I drop a `BrickControl` onto the `StackingPanel` it gets added to the `FlowLayoutPanel`, but in an unspecific order and I cannot reorder the controls like I usually could in a `FlowLayoutPanel`. I found out that there is a `FlowLayoutPanelDesigner` in System.Windows.Forms.Design, but it's set to internal. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

**My goal:** I was going to use a custom designer for the `FlowLayoutPanel` to override `CanParent(Control)` method and make sure that only one type of `BrickControl` is added. And for some visual feedback during drag & drop.

**Question:** Is there a workaround or something like this to realize my idea?

Comment: Can you show the drop code that adds the control to the flp`?

Comment: @TaW I don't have code for this, because it's the default implementation of `ParentControlDesigner`. But I should have mentioned that this is all during design time in Visual Studio.